In WP Elementor, I can't change the size of my image
ENVIRONMENT:
WordPress 6.5.3
Elementor Version 3.21.8
I want to make a sale page with Elementor. I use a simple free Elementor template. I selected the template "Canva Elementor" in the settings of the page (see screenshot)

PROBLEM:
My webp image keeps always the same size whatever size I choose:

WHAT DID I DO?
I inspected the code and I can see this element class for the image is width:100%

I don't understand, so I checked my custom CSS in my "Personalize theme" page :
.site-title{display:none;}
.elementor-224 {
    max-width: 100%!important;
}
.style-two .header-bottom {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.main-navigation ul li {
    font-size: 1em!important;}
.header-social ul li {
    font-size: 1em!important;
}
.footer-t {
    
    padding-top: 30px!important;
    padding-bottom: 30px!important;
    padding-left: 30px!important;
    padding-right: 30px!important;
}
.widget {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0!important;
}
.footer-b{display:none;}

.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text{
    width:300px!important;
    font-size:1.1em!important;
}

.inline_textfield{
    display:inline-block;
        margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.post-thumbnail .svg-holder {
    width: 150px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
    height: 150px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
}
.post-thumbnail .fallback-svg {
    width: 100%; /* Ensure the SVG scales properly */
    height: 100%; /* Ensure the SVG scales properly */
}

I don't see anything wrong. So I cleared the cache and tried with different browsers (Firefox, IE, Chrome). There is still the same issue. The image doesn't want to change.
So I switch to the Twenties theme, and I get the same issue.
So I updated Elementor, but I still have the same issue.
So I deactivated all the plugins except Elementor, and I still have the same issue.
So I switched my Webp image with a PNG, and I still have the same issue.
For all these reasons, I think ELementor is bugging or I didn't see something in my parameters.

On Elementor, just change that Image Resolution from thumbnail to Full.
full image resolution
